# determinant of the sum of two matrices det(A+B)

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have met with a formula, that
$$\det(\lambda^2A + \lambda B +C) = \lambda^{2n} \det(A) + \text{ lower order terms}.$$
Here, $\lambda$ is a scalar and $A,B,C$ are $n \times n$-matrices. 
Can you help me prove it?

Comment: Do you mean lower order terms of $\lambda$?

Comment: Try induction on n

Comment: Yes, lower order terms of $\lambda$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No better a time than now to learn about the [exterior algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra) perspective on determinants! Unless you prefer inductive proofs...

Let's view these matrices as linear maps $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ instead. In terms of the exterior algebra approach, we wish to show that $\Lambda^n ( \lambda^2 \alpha + \lambda \beta + \gamma)$ is $\lambda^{2n} \Lambda \alpha$ up to lower order terms in $\lambda$.

The determinant here will be $ (\lambda^2 \alpha + \lambda \beta + \gamma )\wedge \cdots \wedge  (\lambda^2 \alpha + \lambda \beta + \gamma)$. Now simply distribute, and collect into terms with the same degree of $\lambda$. The term with the highest degree of $\lambda$ will be the one where we have picked out all the $\lambda^2 \alpha$'s, and that's $\Lambda^n \lambda^2 \alpha = \lambda^{2n} \Lambda^n \alpha$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I will learn about exterior algebra.

Comment: If that ends up being too much to learn for the time being, then try solving the problem using the fact that determinant is alternating multilinear in the rows. Then expand out the whole expression using multilinearlity in each row, pulling the $\lambda$'s out as well. We get a large sum, which we sort into groups based on the degree of $\lambda$. Then the top cofficient, the one corresponding to $\lambda^{2n}$, will be $\text{det}(A)$.

Comment: This is a more comprehensive explanation. I would like to ask that $det(A+B）=det(A)+other terms$, is it right?

Comment: What would you like to ask?

Comment: $det(A+B)=det(A)$+ other terms, is is right?

Comment: Yes you could say that. Use the fact that it's multilinear in the rows again.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $ \det(\lambda A)=\lambda^n\det (A) $ where $ A\in M_n(R) $ for some commutative ring $ R $.